# Azure application IP get blacklisted in spamhaus

Tags: azure, api, email, ip, blacklist

I have deployed my web api on azure, after some time my api doesn't able to send email using smtp which i have configured. after two weeks i get the reason that my IP is blacklisted in spamhaus and that's why my application not able to send order confirmation emails. what is alternative when it again get blacklisted

Comment: Did you read this article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/troubleshoot-outbound-smtp-connectivity

Comment: Yes i did, but nothing found regrading this

Comment: Refer to this [article](https://bobcares.com/blog/spamhaus-blocking-outgoing-mail/) with the help of Support Engineers.

Answer (score 1):

What @silent was trying to point out is that the article explains your issue.  You need to get an SMTP relay service to sent email from most Azure IPs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/troubleshoot-outbound-smtp-connectivity

***Recommended method of sending email***

We recommend you use authenticated SMTP relay services (that typically connect through TCP port 587 or 443 but support other ports, too) ***to send email from Azure VMs or from Azure App Services***. These services are used to maintain IP or domain reputation to minimize the possibility that third-party email providers will reject the message. Such SMTP relay services include but aren't limited to SendGrid. It's also possible you have a secure SMTP relay service that's running on-premises that you can use.

You can now get [SendGrid](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/SendGrid.SendGrid?tab=PlansAndPrice) or [MailJet](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/mailjet.mailjet?tab=PlansAndPrice) on Azure basic plan is free